# Good Draw-Centric CSS/Webdesign Apps for mac?

Tags: css, macos

but I am horrible at design and CSS. I was wondering if there are any good apps where I can design websites by drawing them (moving textboxes, images around etc) easily in.

Essentially something like iWeb where design is easy but something a bit more complete (make nice divs, form design etc). I want a good way to put up a design for somethings I want to program quickly.

Again, for the Mac.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

WISYIWIG web editors are terrible. Take your time and learn how to do it right.

But if you must get something done quickly take a look at [Coda](http://panic.com/coda/)